# Chrome extension to open Powerpoint / Documents. How does this work?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, google-chrome-extensions

I have installed this extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-office-viewer-beta/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj/details

And now I am able to view .ppt and .doc files in my browser.
I am perplexed. How does this work? It doesn't seem to be converting the files on a remote server. It seems to actually processing them on my PC!

Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is used Google's [**`Native Client`**](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) (which provides a sandboxed environment for native code extensions). It's very similar to Chrome's built-in PDF support.

Answer (score 1):

It embeds the [QuickOffice](https://support.google.com/quickoffice/answer/2986862?hl=en) application and turns it into a web based extension. This can be seen in the .cfx (Chrome extension) archive which includes the QuickOffice binaries such as `platform_specific/x86_64/word_x86_64.nexe`